# Change fontsize of html elements on button click in angular

Tags: angular, font-size

Here is my template.

```
<div>
<p>First</p>
<p>Second</p>
<div>
<p>Third</p>
<p>Fourth</p>
</div>
<button>+</button>
<button>+</button>
```

On clicking +/- I want to increase/decrease font size of say first three Paragraph Element.
How to do it

Comment: [An example directly from the Angular docs](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eqrlpaajlvv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template:

```
<div>
    <p [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':fontSize}">First</p>
    <p [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':fontSize}">Second</p>
    <p [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':fontSize}">Third</p>
    <p [ngStyle]="{'font-size.px':fontSize}">Fourth</p>
</div>
<button (click)="IncrFontSize()">+</button>
<button (click)="DecreFontSize()">-</button>
```

Code:

```
   fontSize = 24;
   IncrFontSize() {
    this.fontSize++;
   }
   DecreFontSize() {
    this.fontSize--;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of the code using Angular's two-way data binding:

```
<div>
  <p [style.font-size.px]="fontSize">First</p>
  <p [style.font-size.px]="fontSize">Second</p>
  <p [style.font-size.px]="fontSize">Third</p>
  <p [style.font-size.px]="fontSize">Fourth</p>
</div>
<button (click)="fontSize = fontSize + 2">+</button>
<button (click)="fontSize = fontSize - 2">-</button>
```

In the component class:

```
export class YourComponent {
  fontSize = 14;
}
```